# Risk measurement of multicallable bonds

Tags: risk-management, callable-bonds

Assume you have bought a multicallable bond where the issuer has the right to redeem the notional at various dates, e.g. a $10$ yr maturity, $5$% coupon yearly and each year one call date. Next, assume your risk management is not very sophisticated so that it is not able to measure the risk of such "exotic" bonds.

Is it deemed to be a conservative approach in terms of risk assessment if you take the first call date as maturity date (instead of the $10$ yrs) and only consider the coupon payment(s) you will receive until then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Bonds with more than 1 posisble call date are not very exotic. This answer applies to a bond with 1 European call date as well.)

That depends on what risk measures you want (or are required to) calculate.

For example, if you're trying to calculate sensitivities to 1bp change interest rate by tenor bucket, then the following simple approach may be good enough for you (although some people may say it's too simple to be acceptable even for this)

Find the option exercise date for yield to worst. (If the bond is putable, which is common in some emerging markets, then the best yield for the bond holder to exercise.)  Assume that the bond issuer will exercise on the YTW date and disregard the optionality for the interest rate risk calculation.

But if your risk scenarios perturb the interest rates by hundreds of basis points (stress tests) then of course this would likely affect the moneyness of the option and the decision whether to exercise them.

However assuming that the first call date will be exercised, even if it is out of the money, will understate the interest rate risk. **Numerical example.** Suppose for concreteness that we calculate IR risk by calculating the option adjusted spread (OAS) from the observed bond price, then perturbing the interest rates one tenor at a time and repricing the bond keeping the OAS constant.

Suppose the bond is trading at 90, can be called at par in 1y, and otherwise matures in 10y. (European call, not "on or after"). Just *making up* some numbers, if you assume that the (far out of the money) call is exercised, then the interest rate sensitivity might be .1 to 1y interest rate and nothing after 1y; while if you assume that the call is not exercised, then the interest rate sensitivity might be 1, mostly to the 10y interest rate.

Vega of a callable bond is not useful, but sometimes you are required to calculate it.

A better (but harder to implement and compute) approach  would be use a 2-dimensional tree (interest rates and credit spread) to get the probability of each call getting exercised. Use sums, weighted by exercise probabilities, of the risk measures under each exercise scenario.

Comment: If we assume 1bp sensitivities, why would it understate the interest rate risk if we assume the bond to be called at the first call date? In fact, if bond prices quote above par then the exercise date based on YTC would be always the first call date. Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: I edited to add some details. It would be strange for a callable bond to trade much above the call price. The option is unlikely to be exercised if the bond is trading below the call price.

Comment: As long as we consider bonds trading below par I certainly agree with you. However, my watchlist comprises more than 2000 callable bonds and none of them trades below par (mostly they trade around 105) So why would we understate the risk of those above-par bonds if we take the first call date?

Comment: Sry, maybe I misunderstood your question? I thought you wanted to make a blanket assumption that the first call would always be exercised, whether it's in the money or not. If you use small (like 1bp) rates bump, and assume that the call will be exercised if it makes economic sense, then it's (mostly) OK. But if the call is not in the money now, then you shouldn't just assume "exercise anyway". Also large (100s of bps) changes in rates would change the calls' moneyness, so you'd need something more complicated.

Comment: Also note that just comparing a coupon bond price to its call price (which is usually par but not always) doesn't quite tell you whether the call in in the money. Comparing the yields under different exercise scenarios considers (with some assumptions) the coupons accruing between now and the call date.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and insights Dimitri! I think this issue can't be solved as easy as I thought initally. I guess that I should go deeper into this topic.

Comment: Please don't get discouraged. Finding the YTW, and then assuming that the decision whether to exercise does not change if rates move a little - isn't very hard. But if you need big rates bumps (that would affect moneyness), or if someone (e.g. model validation, regulators) require something more complicated, then a more complicated calculation would be harder, but still not impossible.

Comment: Why would it be reasonable to assume that the issuer calls at the date of the YTW?

Comment: It's really not exact, but the best guess that's easy to nail down. It's possible that currently you expect them to call, but later things change, issuer's credit spread widens a lot, bond price goes down, and they don't call. A more complete risk report might show the effect of this on risk. Also, very rarely but sometimes issuers call bonds trading below call price (for capital structure or some such).

Comment: Sounds like US munis where bonds often trade premium (but not excessively) to call strike (even if they're current) because of tax reasons and potentislly knowledge of issuer's capital plans (seen it).